# Sending the current date via ajax to my .net handler, how to pass a safe date?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime

I need to pass a date, that will be generated via javascript to a asp.net http handler that is services in ajax requests.

On the .net side, I will take the date passed in a cast it to DateTime.

The date has to have: yyyy, mm, dd, and minutes and seconds.

How can I format a date in javascript to this format?

**Using jquery**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET AJAX already in your project, Dave Ward explains how to use ASP.NET AJAX extensions for this purpose in his blog post [Work smarter: MS AJAX's JavScript type extensions](http://encosia.com/2007/12/04/work-smarter-ms-ajaxs-javascript-base-type-extensions/):

> Simplify formatting client side dates
>   with Date.format If you’ve spent much
>   time working with dates in JavaScript,
>   you know what a hassle it can
>   sometimes be. To greatly ease this,
>   ASP.NET AJAX extends the JavaScript
>   Date object with a formatting function
>   that closely mimics the ToString
>   formatting paradigm that we’ve been
>   using for years. Here are a few
>   examples:

```
var today = new Date('12/3/2007');

var shortDate = today.format('d');
// d formats the date as MM/dd/yyyy
// shortDate == '12/03/2007'

var longDate = today.format('D');
// D formats the date as dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
// longDate == 'Monday, 03 December 2007'

var customDate = today.format('MMMM, yyyy');
// Custom format string to format the date as MMMM, yyyy
// customDate == 'December, 2007'
```

> Date.format accepts most of the
>   standard DateTime format strings, such
>   as d and D. If none of those suit your
>   needs, Date.format also provides
>   almost unlimited flexibility via
>   custom formatting strings. For a full
>   list of formatting string parameters,
>   see the [Standard DateTime Format
>   Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom DateTime Format
>   Strings](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) reference pages on MSDN.

Comment: the links at the bottom have all kinds of variations. For example: var myCustomDateTime = today.format('G');  // "09/27/2006 14:15:39"